# can't remove a string from bytes in python3 by regex

Tags: python, regex, tornado, python-3.4

*i have an error when I use re.sub in python 3
**my code is:

```
 chunk = re.sub(b'-----------------------------(.+)--\r\n', '', chunk
```

and i have this error:

```
   Type Error: sequence item 0: `expected` a bytes-like object, str found
```

it is working in python2 but in python3.4 doesn't work.
In addition i use tornadofreamwork
please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacement part also must be a byte string.

```
chunk = re.sub(b'-----------------------------(.+)--\r\n', b'', chunk)
```

Example:

```
>>> chunk = b'-----------------------------5313032314004\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="4.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\xff\xd8\xff'
>>> re.sub(b'-', b'', chunk)
b'5313032314004\r\nContentDisposition: formdata; name="file"; filename="4.jpg"\r\nContentType: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\xff\xd8\xff'
```

Comment: no! when i use r before string , this error occur::::can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Comment: chunk = b'-----------------------------5313032314004\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="4.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n\xff\xd8\xff\........Act and i try to remove  '------------5313032514004\r\n from it

Comment: exactly chunk is a part of a file , I received it from a form by Ajax

Comment: @seydimanfeyzbakhsh replacement part must be a byte string. check my update.

Comment: @ Avinash Raj: i try b'-----...' but is not working.

Comment: did you change the second part? `b'', chunk)`

Comment: @ Avinash Raj:thank you my dear friend it's working!